# Xamarin Android: Android.Views.InflateException - Error when loading Layout

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I wrote a Xamarin Android app in Visual Studio to scan QR-Barcodes. I have two layouts and two lctivitys in my project. When i start the app, the emulator loads and the App starts correctly without a problem (The main screen is just one button that leads to a new Intent, which is my second layout/activity). Now when i click the button to switch to the next activity / layout, i get an exception, and the app crashes.

The exception happens in ActNewOrder.cs, where "**SetContentView(Resource.Layout.lay1Copy);**" is:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

i couldn't find anything on the internet, so i hope you guys can help me out.

Thank you very much in advance!

Here is my code for the ActNewOrder.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Gms.Vision.Barcodes;
using Android.Gms.Vision;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Runtime;
using System;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android;
using Android.Content.PM;
using static Android.Gms.Vision.Detector;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Content;

namespace InstandhaltungApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "ActNewOrder", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar")]
    public class ActNewOrder : AppCompatActivity, ISurfaceHolderCallback, IProcessor
    {
        SurfaceView cameraPreview;
        TextView txtResult;
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
        CameraSource cameraSource;
        const int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
                            {
                                //Request permission
                                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
                                {
                   Manifest.Permission.Camera
                                }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                                return;
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                cameraSource.Start(cameraPreview.Holder);
                            }
                            catch (InvalidOperationException)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.lay1Copy);

            cameraPreview = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.cameraPreview);
            txtResult = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtResult);

            barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .SetBarcodeFormats(BarcodeFormat.QrCode)
                .Build();
            cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .SetRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .Build();

            cameraPreview.Holder.AddCallback(this);
            barcodeDetector.SetProcessor(this);
        }

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
        {

        }

        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                //Request permission
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
                {
                   Manifest.Permission.Camera
                }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                cameraSource.Start(cameraPreview.Holder);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {

            }
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            cameraSource.Stop();
        }

        public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
        {
            SparseArray qrcodes = detections.DetectedItems;
            if (qrcodes.Size() != 0)
            {
                txtResult.Post(() => {
                    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
                    vib.Vibrate(1000);
                    txtResult.Text = ((Barcode)qrcodes.ValueAt(0)).RawValue;
                });
            }
        }

        public void Release()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the layout file, lay1Copy.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_left_gl"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".02"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_right_gl"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".98"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_left_gl"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".48"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_right_gl"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".52"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_top_gl"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".01"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_gl"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/elem_bottom_gl"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".85"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/elem_bottom_gl2"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.99"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/main_left_gl"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/main_right_gl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_top_gl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_bottom_gl" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:text="Please focus Camera to QR Code"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/main_left_gl"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/main_right_gl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_bottom_gl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/elem_bottom_gl" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:text="Wagen ansehen"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/main_left_gl"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button_left_gl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/elem_bottom_gl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/elem_bottom_gl2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReset"
        android:text="Reset QR-Code"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button_right_gl"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/main_right_gl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/elem_bottom_gl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/elem_bottom_gl2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do not revert the change made to your post. Putting images of code instead of code (or error message) is discouraged on StackOverflow. However, even if you have to use images, they must be included into your post as images, not links.

Comment: okay, i just edited my post as it was suggested by stackoverflow, but i couldn't add a picture unless i have 10 reputations. I'll edit it so there is no picture but only code then.

Comment: Is the problem resolved?

Comment: yes it is, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every android `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` must be added, even with constraint layout.

The problem in your xml layout is starting from your `SurfaceView`, you only have `android:width` and `android:height` defined in your views.

So to resolve the problem, you need to change `android:width` to `android:layout_width` and `android:height` to `android:layout_height`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved the problem. After that i had another problem with the cameraPreview, but solved by adding a camera to the backside of the AVD. Again, thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, and my layout does not contain any android:width and android:height properties

Answer (score 0):

I am also face this same issue and my layout does not contain any android:width and android:height properties. I missed to add theme for my activity. I solved this issue by following steps:

Create a styles.xml file under Resources\values\ folder with below codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<resources>
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

In MainActivity.cs define the Activity attribute to leverage AppTheme like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "DinexFeedback", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",Theme ="@style/AppTheme")]
public class MainActivity : Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity
{
   ...
}
```

**Updating the answer here because this might help others...**

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException:

Make sure the necessary nuget package installed in visual studio.

I used card view in my project, i got this issue becoz i didn't install Xamarin.Android.Support.cardview.

so we should install all support nuget package in order to support all widgets here i use card view.

click on project -> Manage Nuget-> check out the installed pakages, if the package were not installed just search the particular package and then download it.

updated on 10/12/2018

check your layout whether all the layout fields are started with capital letter. for ex : In android we used <**view**> in small letter but In c# we should use <**View**> otherwise it throws the inflate view exception.