# Xamairin forms : Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: xamarin.android, inflate-exception

Research a lot about this issue and found the same question, which doesn't solve my problem. so starting a new question.
[Xamarin Android: Android.Views.InflateException - Error when loading Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460907/xamarin-android-android-views-inflateexception-error-when-loading-layout)

Getting  **Xamairin forms : Android.Views.InflateException: Timeout exceeded getting exception** details when loading layout.

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFCDD2"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_sign_up"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have not used layout:width and layout:height properties in my axml and only using an icon having 4kb size.

Please suggest a solution for this issue, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Getting Xamairin forms : Android.Views.InflateException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details when loading layout.

There are two things needs to be confirmed before using `TextInputLayout`:

1. Please make sure, `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` lib is correctly referenced in your `Xamarin.Android` project. If you are using `Xamarin.Forms`, it should be referenced by default.
2. Please make sure the Activity is of type `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`.

If none of the above things help, please provide a basic demo that can reproduce the problem.

Update:

Upon testing on the project you shared. I found you need to use a `Theme.AppCompat` theme for your activity, you can do that by following below steps:

1. Create a `styles.xml` file under `Resources\values\` folder with below codes:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   <resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```
2. In `MainActivity.cs` define the `Activity` attribute to leverage `AppTheme` like this:

   ```
   [Activity(Label = "DinexFeedback", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",Theme ="@style/AppTheme")]
   public class MainActivity : Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity
   {
      ...
   ```

Then the project will run fine.

Comment: I change Activity to Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity and I am using latest stable version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Design(27.0.2)

Comment: I don't know how to check the Xamarin.Android.Support.Design lib reference?

Comment: check whether `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` nuget package is referenced in your project. If you are not familiar with nuget package in Visual Studio, please refer to [Install and use a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design is present in the References folder of the project

Comment: great, and is your activity inherits from `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`? If so, I may need a sample project that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Could you provide that through online repository?

Comment: I'll have it tested tonight, currently my PC is not available.

Comment: You need to use `Theme.AppCompat` theme, please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException:

Make sure the necessary nuget package installed in visual studio.

I used card view in my project, i got this issue becoz i didn't install Xamarin.Android.Support.cardview.

so we should install all support nuget package in order to support all widgets here i use card view.

click on project -> Manage Nuget-> check out the installed pakages, if the package were not installed just search the particular package and then download it.

**updated on 10/12/2018**

check your layout whether all the layout fields are started with capital letter. for ex : In android we used  in small letter but In c# we should use  otherwise it throws the inflate view exception.